# How to create an "exact" copy of a directory using the shell

Tags: bash, file-copy

Using Bash, how can I copy a directory to another place while keeping all properties exactly the same, including timestamp and permission and all other properties?

Answer (score 3):

The tool you are likely looking for is `rsync`, a standard tool on many Linux platforms. When used with the appropriate options, it can for all purposes make a 1-to-1 copy of a source directory to a target.

```
rsync -aHSAX -ih --progress /path/to/source_dir/ /path/to/target_dir
```

This will copy the entire *content* of the directory `source_dir` to the `target_dir`, while preserving users, permissions, timestamps, ACLs and extended attributes (thanks to @K-att- for reminding me of the last two) and copy symlinks as symlinks. Note that the filesystem of your copy target has to support the same attributes as the filesystem where the source resides, otherwise you will get error messages.

If you want to copy the containing directory `source_dir` too (i.e. you end up with a newly-created directory `target_dir/source_dir/`), then you need to omit the trailing `/` on `source_dir/`.

Another approach is to use `cp` with appropriate options.

```
cp -r --preserve=all /path/to/source_dir /path/to/target_dir
```

will also copy recursively and preserve all supported attributes (owner, permissions, timestamps, ACLs, SELinux context, extended attributes).